# How to download a video from rtmp protocol from behind proxy using rtmpdump

Tags: video, tcp, proxy, streaming, rtmp

I am trying to download video from rtmp://flash.dce.harvard.edu/bounce/mp4:2015/01/14328/L01/14328-20140902-L01-4-h264-av1248-16x9-852x480.mp4. My college internet runs behing proxy, Is there a way I can set http/https proxy to rtmpdump?